# Creating a wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, function

Just want to know that if I'm going to create a new wordpress theme, what about functions.php, should I need to create a new functions file, or just copy it from other wordpress theme. I have read codex but it only tells about the templates needed to create a new theme.

Comment: If you tpye "create wordpress theme" in google, I'm pretty sure you'll find a nice tutorial...

Comment: Both will work. Wordpress will detect the function.php and it content. But what if you just.. TRY :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a new functions.php file if you don't want custom functions in your theme.

See [this thread](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/using-without-functionsphp-would-my-theme-work) for more information - not including functions.php doesn't make any difference for your custom theme.

Comment: Additionally, if you want to create a new functions.php file, you can create one from scratch if you'd like. You can also copy one from another theme, it'll probably just give you a lot of functions you don't need for your site.

Answer (score 2):

- The theme functions file is a template used by Word-press themes. It acts like a plug-in and gets automatically loaded in both admin and front-end pages of a Word-press site.
- The **functions.php** file can be found in your theme’s folder.
  You don't need to create a new functions.php file when you want to put your own function in function.php just paste that code in your themes functions.php file.
- You can look into these Reference Links to understand more about function.php file :-

  [Functions_File_Explained](https://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained)